# azure data factory - performing full IDL for the first slice

Tags: azure, integration, azure-data-factory

I'm working on data factory POC to replace existing data integration solution that loads data from one system to another. The existing solution extracts all data available until present point in time and then on consecutive runs extracts new/updated data that changed since last time it ran. Basically IDL (initial data load) first and then updates.

Data factory works somewhat similar and extracts data in slices. However I need the first slice to include all the data from the beginning of time. I could say that pipeline start time is "the beginning of time", but that would create too many slices.

For example I want it to run daily and grab daily increments. But I want to extract data for last 10 years first. I don't want to have 3650 slices created to catch up. I want the first slice to have WindowStart parameter overridden and set to some predetermined point in the past. And then consecutive slices to use normal WindowStart-WindowEnd time interval.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about you create two pipelines, one as a "run once" which transfers all the initial data, then clone that one, so you copy all the datasets and linked service references in the pipeline.  Then add the schedule to it, and a SQL query to fetch only new data which uses the date variables?  You'll need something like this in the second pipeline:

```
"source":
{
    "type": "SqlSource",
    "SqlReaderQuery": "$$Text.Format('SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE createdDate > \\'{0:yyyyMMdd-HH}\\'', SliceStart)"
},
"sink":
{
    ...
}
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: wBob, I was contemplating that idea. The thing is I have multiple entities to extract, up to 20. so i would have to create extra 20 pipelines and i might need to multiply all that by number of customers. so it will get messy quick.. thanks for you suggestion though.